# How To Import NSString Value Into A Different View Controller?

Tags: xcode, global-variables, constants, uilabel

I have an application where I am setting a zip code value in a UITextField on one view. When I switch views, I would like that value to be displayed as a UILabel. I know how to do this within one view controller but not between two. I have attempted to set the 'zip code value' to a constant string in a header file called 'globals.h' and then recall it but it always crashes. Here are some code samples:

This is the globals.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface globals 

extern NSString *zipCodeValue;

@end
```

This is the globals.m file:

```
#import "globals.h"

@implementation globals

NSString *zipCodeValue = @"default value";

@end
```

This is the first view (where the zip code is entered into the text field. Both interface and implementation):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ZipCodeEntryViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *zipCode;
    UIButton *doneButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *zipCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton;

-(IBAction) tapBackground:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) doneButtonClick:(id)doneButton;

@end

#import "ZipCodeEntryViewController.h"
#import "MillersAppAppDelegate.h"
#import "AddressViewController.h"
#import "globals.h"
#define MAX_LENGTH 5

@implementation ZipCodeEntryViewController
@synthesize zipCode, doneButton;

-(IBAction) doneButtonClick:(id)doneButton{
    MillersAppAppDelegate *delegate = (MillersAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication     sharedApplication] delegate];
    AddressViewController *addressView = [[AddressViewController     alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddressViewController" bundle:nil];
    [delegate switchViews:self.view toView:addressView.view];
    //using the global string to store the text field content
    zipCodeValue=zipCode.text;
    //the button is clicked and the view changes to addressView while NSLogging the correct value. So far, so good.
    NSLog(@"%@", zipCodeValue); 
    [addressView release];
}

-(IBAction) tapBackground:(id)sender{
    [zipCode resignFirstResponder];
}
```

So, everything appears ok at this point (it logs it out correctly). I'm assuming the constant variable 'zipCodeValue' will continue to retain it's set value now even though the view controller has changed. BUT when I attempt to apply it in the new view controller (AddressViewController) it does nothing to the label. This is the method I used (I named it in the header file; 'zipCodeEntry' is the UILabel that I named initialized and connected to the target in Interface Builder):

```
-(void)setZipCode{
zipCodeEntry.text=zipCodeValue;
}
```

I am now thoroughly confused, I have reason to believe my brain is missing something since I'm new to this. Sorry if this is long-winded, I didn't want to leave anything out. I'm clearly a beginner. AGGGG!!!

Comment: What about storing zipCodeValue in your App Delegate where you can access from any viewcontroller?

Comment: I attempted that by storing it in my App Delegate which is "MillersAppAppDelegate.h" and then importing the header file into the ZipCodeEntryViewController.m file. It didn't allow me to access zipCodeValue (like when I went to type it, it didn't have the predictive text saying that it's an available option).

Comment: Ok yeah, I figured out how to store it in my App Delegate and then access it. Thanks, just had to read up on how to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[ud setObject:zipCodeValue forKey:@"myKey"];
[ud synchronize];
```

And to load it:

```
NSString *a = [ud objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

You can load and save it everywhere in your app

Comment: I'm so confused right now haha. I've set the NSUserDefaults code in a method in the global file but when I go to load it in the ZipCodeEntryViewController.m, it doesn't recognize "ud" as something that's previously been declared. Did I place them in the wrong files?

Comment: in every ViewController you must declare : NSUserDefauls *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Comment: Where do I declare the original NSUserDefaults code you put in the original answer? Is that done in the global implementation file? I'm confused as to where that code is originally placed.